# bluetooth extended inquiry response

Tags: bluetooth

I'm trying to use the bluetooth extended inquiry response to package a brief message, but I can't seem to find any API that allows access to this  information (I'm language agnostic, I just need to find a way to get this to work!) nor any examples where this data is even being utilized.  From what I have found, I BELIEVE that most stacks now send EIR data when they respond to an inquiry response?  Although even that isn't really documented other than "this "supports" EIR.  Is there anyone that can point me in the right direction?

FYI, I have access to machines running Ubuntu, Win 7, and probably a couple of other OS's if need be.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux you can use the BlueZ utilities [hciconfig](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hciconfig) and [hcitool](http://linux.die.net/man/1/hcitool).

For `hciconfig`, check out the options `inqmode` (extended is mode 2) and `inqdata`.  With hcitool, you can put a device in inquiry using `inq`.

Comment: But putting a device into inquiry still only returns a normal inquiry?